# Can I access the current element in a jQuery templates custom function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have just started using [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl).

I have a question that the documentation hasn't been able to answer for me (yet).

My template is...

```
<script id="restaurant-review-template" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <span class="rating rating-${rating}">
            ${$item.getRating()}
        </span>
    </li>
</script>
```

...and my invocation code is...

```
$('#restaurant-review-template').tmpl(allRestaurants, {
    getRating: function() {
        // Is it possible to access the array element here?
        // Ideally, if `this` was the current array member...
        return new Array((this.rating || 0) + 1).join('*');
    }
}).appendTo('#cont')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uMuPA/).

In my `allRestaurants` array, I have objects which have a `rating` property which contains an number.

I want to return a list of asterixes for the number in the `rating` property. For example, if the `rating` property held `4`, I'd like to output `****`.

I know I could do something like...

```
allRestaurants = allRestaurants.filter(function(element) {
   element.asterixes = new Array((element.rating || 0) + 1).join('*');
   return true;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7HK6/).

...but I'd rather not polute the array with that extra property just for the template.

So, within a custom template function such as above, is there a way to access the current array element (I did `console.log(this, arguments)` and couldn't see anything useful).

If not, what is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all item's data is located in `this.data`, so you can reach rating value with `this.data.rating`.

```
element.asterixes = new Array((this.data.rating || 0) + 1).join('*');
```

Comment: Well, that's a bit embarrassing. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks :)